# Why does Process.WaitForExit block even though I have it in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, process

C# 3.5 Winforms app.

I have a timer that fires every 30 seconds on separate thread (all it does is write a string of text to the VS output window).

I also have another thread that waits for a certain process to end if it starts up.  For example winword.exe.

In that thread I have this code:

```
p.WaitForExit();
```

And it will sit there and wait for `winword.exe` to exit.  That works fine.

However, while it is sitting there waiting for `winword.exe` to exit, the 30 second timer on a completely separate thread (that sends text to the output window) never runs.

If I wait 3 minutes (so the other timer should of run 6 times at this point, but it does not while `WaitForExit()` is waiting), and then I exit `winword.exe`; all of sudden my other timer starts running 6 times at once.  It is like there is a backlog of the timer event and all of a sudden .Net wants to run it all at the same time.

Why does `p.WaitForExit()` seem to block my whole application even though I have it executing from a separate thread in my app (not the main UI thread)?

Edit:  Yes it is in a separate thread.  Here is the code that I use to launch it:

```
        try
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(ProcessCheck); // Kick off a new thread
            t.Start();

            ConfigLogger.Instance.LogInfo("++ ProcessCheck thread started @ " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception ipwse)
        {
            ConfigLogger.Instance.LogInfo(ipwse.Message + " " + ipwse.StackTrace);
        }
```

Here is the ProcessCheck() method that I have:

```
foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword"))
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {                                                                                 
        try
        {
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is actually running on a different thread?

Comment: As a general debugging tip: when your app seams hung, break in under a debugger and look at the stack of the UI thread. That should explain it.

Comment: What kind of timer is it? If is a Windows.Forms.Timer, then that explains it, since a Windows Forms timer raises its event handle on the UI thread (and now you are blocking the message pump)

Comment: You are saying the are running on separate threads but still sounds like the Timer and the process instance are using the same Thread

Comment: Please post all your relevant code (both timer/thread creation, handlers...)

Comment: @vcsjones  Yes, it is a timer on the actual form.  Is that the problem?  But why does Process.WaitForExit block the message pump if that is executing from a separate thread?

Comment: @fraXis because it isn't on a separate thread. The `Tick` event is always raised on the UI thread, regardless of what thread started it.

Comment: @fraXis to be clear, are you using the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class, a different timer class, or are you using the word "timer" generically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.Invoke`, if done from a WinForms form, will block the UI thread until the process has exited.  If the Timer is System.Windows.Forms.Timer, the Tick event is raised on the UI thread.  If the UI thread is blocked, that would explain why the Tick event is never raised.

Comment: Do I need the "this.Invoke" here?  Is there an alternative I should use?

Comment: You have the right idea Peter, wrong explanation. Calling `Control.Invoke` runs the specified delegate on the UI thread and blocks the calling thread until the UI thread completes its execution. What's happening in the code above is that `p.WaitForExit` is blocking both the UI thread (because its executing on the UI thread), and the calling thread (which is waiting on the UI thread).

Comment: @fraXis You can use BeginInvoke; but that would still call WaitForExit on the UI thread and block it.  If the code that calls Invoke currently, is in a background thread, you can call WaitForExit directly which will cause the background thread to block instead of the UI thread.  If you provide some more detail about what you're really trying to do, someone might be able to provide more detail.

Comment: @Tergiver Right, whatever thread calls Invoke will be blocked.  Point is that the UI thread is blocked on WaitForExit and can't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because the following program shows that what you're doing works as long as you're doing the threading right.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BackgroundWorker shortThread = new BackgroundWorker(), waitThread = new BackgroundWorker();

    shortThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    shortThread.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (shortThread.CancellationPending)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Hello World...");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        };

    waitThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    waitThread.DoWork += (s, e) => { Process.Start("winword.exe").WaitForExit(); };

    shortThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    waitThread.RunWorkerAsync();

    Console.ReadLine();

    shortThread.CancelAsync();
    waitThread.CancelAsync();
}
```

So, it seems to me that you're issuing the `WaitForExit()` on the main thread instead of a separate thread.